# Index.php in URL on my live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for one of my projects I solved the problem of removing the index.php from my URLS locally but yesterday I configured my code on staging server I enable the rewite mod in apache on my staging server. The config file and the .htaccess are the same one I used for my local machine. But i still have the problem of index.php in URl

My config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

My database file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mediabox
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The url of my staging server is

```
 http://stage.carrier.com/home/box/12
```

when i try to open it using the above url its give 404 error

but when i try to open with this url it opens

```
http://stage.carrier.com/index.php/home/box/12
```

What can be the main reason ? 
Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite enabled ?

Comment: Are you using a shared host? or you configured the server itself. Just for the record, if you configured the server yourself, did you update the directive `AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf. If AllowOverride is set to None, `.htaccess` will not be used by apache

Answer (score 0):

You're on an Microsoft-IIS/7.5 server. `.htaccess` files are for Apache webservers, and will be ignored by ASP.NET.

I'm sure IIS is wonderful in its own regards, but it probably isn't the most optimal solution for PHP applications, and I would recommend using a regular LAMP stack for your CI/PHP projects.